# GWT NoClassDefFoundError com/google/gwt/shared/GWTBridge

Tags: java, gwt, junit

I've recently upgraded my GWT from 2.1 -> 2.6.0 however this is breaking a test case, when running the method

```
handlerManager.addHandler(MouseOverEvent.getType(), handler);
```

I get the following error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/shared/GWTBridge
at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.PrivateMap.<init>(PrivateMap.java:65)
at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.init(DomEvent.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent$Type.<init>(DomEvent.java:68)
at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseOverEvent.<clinit>(MouseOverEvent.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWTBridge
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.msLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
... 32 moreisc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.Clas
```

When i put the gwt-dev.jar in the dependencies .pom the error goes away however I then get a compiler WARNING - however can this be ignored ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this dependency to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
    <artifactId>requestfactory-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks ! Worked perfectly.